# How can I rotate an element with css without breaking the "flow" of the layout?

Tags: html, css, transform

[image]

Top left box: this is the original table.

Middle box: this is what happens when I apply:

```
.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

to the red element.

Bottom Right box: This is what I ultimately want the middle box to look like. As you can see, the table containing the red element treats the latter properly by fully containing the latter in its top left  element **without any sort of overflowing.**

What do I need to apply to the middle box to make it behave like the third?

**Obviously I am using a very simplified example to illustrate a point**

```
<div>
<table id='one'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class='red'></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="blue"></div></td>
        <td><div class="blue"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div>
<table id='two'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class='red rotate'></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="blue"></div></td>
        <td><div class="blue"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div>
<table id='three'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class='red'></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="blue"></div></td>
        <td><div class="blue"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
table, th, td { 
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#two { 
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:350px;
}

#three { 
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:700px;
}

.red { 
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:red;
}

#three .red { 
    width: 50px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color:red;
}

.blue { 
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

Comment: ***apply to the middle box to make it behave like the third*** what do you mean by this? do you mean `box`as `table`? if so the third table is different from the middle one, I don't understand what you really want here.

Comment: @KingKing: OP wants to rotate the red area, using CSS, and to forcing its parent to expand its height (to accommodate the rotated-width).

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks, I was confused by the OP's HTML code. If so he should have added code for just 1 table. No need for more 2 tables.

Comment: Looks like it's hard to do it **beautifully** like the **LayoutTransform** which you can do in WPF, transform in CSS is some kind of **RenderTransform** in WPF, which does not affect the layout (except the children of course will be affected by the parent's transform). So you can only try changing the CSS for the `td` when the inner div is rotated to adjust the layout, to do so, you should add class `rotate` for the `td`, not for the inner `div`. Here is the demo I've tried http://jsfiddle.net/ZUW3k/ There is a high chance that it's not what you **actually** want.

Comment: I presume you are adding the `rotate` class dynamically? can you (at the same time) add a class to its containing td, and set the height there?

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest solution I can find is to use the :has selector to modify the parent td whenever the .rotate class is added to a child element. This, combined with display: absolute and setting the top and right properties achieves what you're going for. You would expect to set right to 50px (the height of the div) and top to 0, but I found you have to add 1px to each to make it look right. Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this extra 1px comes from how the div interacts with the 1px border width of its parent before it is rotated. Here's the working code:

```css
table, th, td { 
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#two { 
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:350px;
}

#three { 
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:700px;
}

.red { 
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:red;
}

#three .red { 
    width: 50px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color:red;
}

.blue { 
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.rotate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 51px;
  right: 1px;
  
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

td:has(.rotate) {
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
<table id='one'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class='red'></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="blue"></div></td>
        <td><div class="blue"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div>
<table id='two'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class='red rotate'></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="blue"></div></td>
        <td><div class="blue"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div>
<table id='three'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class='red'></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="blue"></div></td>
        <td><div class="blue"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are setting the initial width and height of `.red`, you can simply swap those properties on rotate.

Replace this:

```
.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

With this:

```
.rotate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/ajilityj/pen/pWqoxy)

Comment: Did you really miss the point of the question? It's about rotating an element without breaking the flow, not resizing a rectangle. The OP spells it out: it's a simple example, to illustrate the point. It's hard to believe you missed it in good faith.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the display to absolute, so that it is taken out of the document flow. You can then add another element behind it, that is invisible so that there is still a space for the element.

```
.rotate{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    position: absolute;
}

.invisibleElement{
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
}
```